# How to play full screen video with this code?

Tags: android

I don't how to play/stream fullscreen video with this code.

```java
final VideoView vd = new VideoView(PlayerActivity.this); 
vd.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
);
linear1.addView(vd);
vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
vd.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
vd.requestFocus();
vd.start();
```

before video load

[image]

after video load

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Full Screen player in Landscape**

`AndroidManifext.xml` (Setting the orientation)

```
 <activity
    android:name=".PlayerActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

`playeractivity.xml` layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".PlayerActivity">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
</VideoView>
```

`PlayerActivity.java` Activity class  :

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private VideoView videoView;
private MediaController mediaController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playeractivity);

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        String fullScreen =  getIntent().getStringExtra("fullScreenInd");
        if("y".equals(fullScreen)){
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }

        // Some video url from resource or from web
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.YOUR_VIDEO_NAME);

        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

        mediaController = new FullScreenMediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.start();

    }
}
```

`FullScreenMediaControler.java` Code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.MediaController;

public class FullScreenMediaController extends MediaController {

private ImageButton fullScreen;
private String isFullScreen;

public FullScreenMediaController(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void setAnchorView(View view) {

    super.setAnchorView(view);

    //image button for full screen to be added to media controller
    fullScreen = new ImageButton (super.getContext());

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    params.rightMargin = 80;
    addView(fullScreen, params);

    //fullscreen indicator from intent
    isFullScreen =  ((Activity)getContext()).getIntent().
            getStringExtra("fullScreenInd");

    if("y".equals(isFullScreen)){
        fullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_exit);
    }else{
        fullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen);
    }

    //add listener to image button to handle full screen and exit full screen events
    fullScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Video1.class);

            if("y".equals(isFullScreen)){
                intent.putExtra("fullScreenInd", "");
            }else{
                intent.putExtra("fullScreenInd", "y");
            }
            ((Activity)getContext()).startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working.     .<activity
        android:name=".PlayerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

Comment: Chandresh, I have updated answer with a working example.

Comment: Can you explain in detail